# How to make a re sizable Vertical handler?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope you know that in http://www.jsfiddle.net we can resize the table.

[image]

So i want wondering how to resize a "Vertical Handler" alone.

Can anyone give me the source ?

Please show an example in http://www.jsfiddle.net if possible.

Comment: Can you give us some more information? Anything at all will help.

Comment: I have added an image to make it even clear !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your looking for the jquery layout plugin. It's very easy to use. Lots of examples here: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but first in Google results, so I'll answer it here.

I found the splitter library at http://methvin.com/splitter/index.html quite serviceable.  It has vertical and horizontal splitters, multiple panels, min and max controls, and so on, along with good demos and documentation.